# char[] or StringBuilder for passwords?

Tags: java, secure-coding

So, because Strings are immutable, we use char[] instead of String to store passwords so that we can erase the characters when we're done with it. Is StringBuilder (or StringBuffer) as safe as a char[] in this case because one can change to value of the password to, say, ""?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, because when you overflow the `char[]` used by the `StringBuilder`, it is replaced by a larger array, but the original array (with part of your password in it) remains in memory until it is garbage-collected.